# Set variables from $.post before anything else is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to load some **arrays** of data from a DB and i was doing it like this:

```
var priorities, users;

$.post("http://"+ document.domain + "/priority",
                function(dat){
                priorities = dat;                       
});

$.post("http://"+ document.domain + "/users",
                function(dat){
                users= dat; 
});
```

Then i want to use this variables inside a plugin and I realized the plugin gets fired before this variables are set even the this code is at the start of the JS file.

Is there any better way to load an array of data from a DB?
In case there is not, how can I do to set this variables before any other code gets executed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.post("http://"+ document.domain + "/priority",
      function(priorities){
            $.post("http://"+ document.domain + "/users",
                function(users){
                DoSomething(priorities, users);
            });                 
       });

function DoSomething(priorities, users){
// User Priorities and Users here
}
```

Other option is to call ajax synchronously, but I don't suggest that :)

EDIT:

```
var priorities, users;

function getPriority(){
    $.post("http://"+ document.domain + "/priority",
            function(dat){
            priorities = dat;                       
    });
}

function getUsers(){
    $.post("http://"+ document.domain + "/users",
            function(dat){
            users= dat; 
    });
}

var dfd = $.Deferred();
dfd
.done([getPriority, getUsers])
.done(function() {
     //here you will have priorities and users
});

dfd.resolve();
```

Comment: The other code is quite big... isn't there any other way? I would prefer to have it separate.

Comment: I want to get 6 different arrays, so I am currently calling `$.post` 6 times and I end up calling a function with 6 parameters `doSomething(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6)`... Isn't there any other method?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use a control flow library, I personally enjoy using async https://github.com/caolan/async which works both in the browser and on the server side.

**Using Async**

```
 async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        $.post("http://"+ document.domain + "/priority", function(dat){
            callback(null, dat); 
        });
    },
    function(priorities, callback){
        $.post("http://"+ document.domain + "/users", function(dat){
            callback(null, priorities, dat);
        });
    }
], function (err, priorities, users) {
    //work with users & priorities
});
```

**Using Callbacks**

```
$.post("http://"+ document.domain + "/priority", function(priorities){
    $.post("http://"+ document.domain + "/users", function(users){
          //work with users & priorities
    });                     
});
```

The reason your running into the problem is because ajax operations are executed async, in that the code does not wait for the operation to be completed but instead fires the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want jQuery **deferred objects**.

```
var priorities, users;
$.when(
  $.post("foo", function(data) { priorities = data; } ), 
  $.post("bar", function(data) { users = data; } )
).done(function() {
  someFunction(priorities, users); // Call your function. Values are set!
})
```

This will only call `someFunction` when all the `post()` functions have been resolved. You can then store the data received in the `post()` function in a higher scope, and access them inside `someFunction()`.